# color map on HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and JavaScript so please be tolerant if this question is trivial but still I appreciate help a lot. :)

I am trying to plot a pressure map using point data read from sensors at discrete locations. In this I approximated the distribution of pressure under each pressure sensor to be a 'paraboloid distribution'. That is, the pressure distribution is assumed to take the shape of a paraboloid of which the center coordinate equals the location of the sensor and the height at center equals the respective sensor's reading. So the formula to find the pressure at other neighboring points is as follows.

> pressure at (x,y) point = -(x - x coordinate of peak)^2/((sensor radius)^2/height at peak) - (y - y coordinate of peak)^2/((sensor radius)^2/height at peak) + height at peak

This is nothing but the normal equation of a paraboloid ((x^2/a) + (y^2/a) + z = 0) adjusted to have the desired center location and the desired height at peak.

This is the code I used to generate the pressure map. (considering only one sensor located at 250,250 with a reading of 500)

```html
<html>
<body>
    <canvas id = 'myCanvas' width = "600" height = "600" style = 'width:600px; height:600px; float:center;'>
        No Image
    </canvas>
    <button type="button" onclick="createFootMap()">Click Me!</button>
    <script>
        function mapAColor(p){
            rComponent = 0;
            gComponent = 0;
            bComponent = 0;
            
            pressureVal = p;
            if (pressureVal < 128){
                rComponent = 0;
                gComponent = pressureVal * 2;
                bComponent = 255;
            } else if (pressureVal < 256) {
                rComponent = 0;
                gComponent = 255;
                bComponent = (255 - pressureVal) * 2 + 1;
            } else if (pressureVal < 384) {
                rComponent = (pressureVal - 256) * 2;
                gComponent = 255;
                bComponent = 0;
            } else if (pressureVal < 512) {
                rComponent = 255;
                gComponent = (511 - pressureVal)*2 + 1;
                bComponent = 0;
            }
            
            var s = "rgb(" + rComponent + "," + gComponent + "," + bComponent + ")";
            return s;
        }
        
        function createFootMap(){
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            
            var i = 0;
            var j = 0;
            var radius = 50;
            var center_x = 250;
            var center_y = 250;
            var peak = 500;
            var p = 0; 
            
            for(i = 0; i < 500; i++){
                for(j = 0; j < 500; j++){
                    p = -(Math.pow((i - center_x), 2) / (Math.pow(radius, 2) / peak)) - (Math.pow((j - center_y), 2) / (Math.pow(radius, 2) / peak)) + peak;
                    ctx.fillStyle = mapAColor(p);
                    ctx.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is as follows.

r = 50, peak = 500

[image: r = 50, peak = 500]

But when I change the radius or the peak pressure values, the result becomes unacceptable.

r = 50, peak = 350

[image: r = 50, peak = 350]

I ran the same code in matlab and I got smooth circular color maps for whatever radius and peak values I used. So if there's anything wrong in the code related to JavaScript syntax, please, I would like to know :)

Thank you.

Comment: What's the output of `s`? I think you might have non-integer values in there.

Comment: s returns a color value in rgb format (ex: "rgb(34, 0, 56)").

Comment: Can you update your code snippet so that it's a working example? Otherwise it's kinda hard to help you debug.

Comment: i edited the post to contain a working example.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but when I try this formula: `p = -(Math.pow((i - center_x),2)/(Math.pow(radius,2)/500)) - (Math.pow((j - center_y),2)/(Math.pow(radius,2)/500)) + peak;` it seems to properly cap the peak.

Comment: yeah, the code works fine for peak value 500. But when i change it to some other value like 350 the map is not a circle anymore. i can't figure out what's wrong..

Comment: Copy and paste the code I provided and try it with `peak = 350`, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yeah, then the shape seems ok. But the color variation is not as i expect. As i understood, i cannot fix that division part to be 500. It has to be the same value i use for peak. So the formula has to be p = -(Math.pow((i - center_x),2)/(Math.pow(radius,2)/peak)) - (Math.pow((j - center_y),2)/(Math.pow(radius,2)/peak)) + peak; and i want it to give a smooth distribution for whatever peak value i use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the variable 'p' being a decimal value. (non integer, as said by Daniel T in his very first comment :) )So that, when i pass that 'p' value to the function mapAColor it returns an rgb format with decimal values for red, green,blue components. Therefore i took the floor of 'p' and sent it as the argument for mapAColor function. Shown below is the corrected code.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 500; j++) {
    p = -(Math.pow((i - center_x), 2) / (Math.pow(radius, 2) / peak)) - (Math.pow((j - center_y), 2) / (Math.pow(radius, 2) / peak)) + peak;
    ctx.fillStyle = mapAColor(Math.floor(p)); //corrected line
    ctx.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

Hope this would help anyone who is interested in this post. And thanks to everyone who spent their precious time to help me find the bug in the code. :)
correct me if my explanation is wrong. :)

Comment: If you are interested in a way to optimize your code (your code crashed my browser), `Math.pow((i - center_x), 2)` should be calculated in the `i` loop, `(Math.pow(radius, 2) / peak)` out of the loops, and instead of 250000 `fillStyle` modifications + `fillRect`, use an ImageData : https://jsfiddle.net/k3ybqs2u/

Comment: yes, that's better :) It avoids unnecessary re-calcualations. Thank you